# Android - further improving efficiency

Tags: android, performance, android-imageview

So [Google](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html) has already told us a thing or two about efficiency, but I'm sort of lost with my application thus far when it comes to efficiency.

To put things short and simple, my app is running slower than I'd like it to. I know that it is most likely due to the extensive code I have in `onCreate` and `onResume`. The bulk of the code that lives in those two methods(especially `onResume`), is from updating/changing certain `ImageView`s to the right source image(the user can customize colors/styles, etc.).

The user changes these settings from a separate menu, outside of where the `ImageView`s live.

My question is then,
    **Is there a more efficient way of updating/changing ImageView source images other than extensive if-else statements in `onCreate` and `onResume`**.

Comment: not really enough to go by from what you say.  If you can cache your images and not reload them that might help.  Layouts are expensive to generate; it might be the layouts rather than loading images. You may need to do some profiling to find out the culprit(s).  Often they are completely different than what you expect.

Comment: You're right about the images - there's just so many of them. I don't believe the layouts are causing it to run slowly - the layouts I have are quite simple and there's just not that many of them.

I sort of answered question by asking it, but thanks for the help.